# Attaching a specific field/variable to the interface being implemented

Tags: java, singleton, instance

I have an interface myInterface which defines two methods, method1, method2. This interface is being implemented by 100 other classes. My requirement is that I am able to to add a field to the interface which is unique to each class. Example: I want to add a field numberOfRequests, which is unique for all classes. So everytime I call method1, I can update numberOfRequests for that class. How do I achieve this by making changes at interface level?

Comment: You can't have a unique field (variable) in an interface.  They are always static final meaning you can have only one instance.  You should have the variable in your classes and modify them there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define instance (non-static) fields in interfaces. You can only add a `static` field to the interface, which then only belongs directly to this interface.

To implement the required functionality, you have to add this field to every single class that implements the interface.

If you are not restricted to using an interface, you can make all implementing classes extending a new class which has the `numberOfRequests` field. This new class could then also implement this interface, if the behaviour all the methods accessing `numberOfRequests` is always the same in all implementing classes.